# publish an existing NX angular library

Tags: angular, nomachine-nx

i have created libraries in nx monorepo using angular as framework.

Now I want to publish it as npm package, but when i run `ng build project-web-shared-ui` it giving `Project 'project-web-shared-ui' does not support the 'build' target.`

How can i publish this library as npm.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your `workspace.json`, there should be `projects` attribute and under it `project-web-shared-ui` and `targets` attribute in it. There should be a `build` target